# Is there a generic equivalent to a hash table, or NameValueCollection that allows multiple values with the same key?

Tags: c#, .net

I found the NameValueCollection but it only supports strings for keys and strings for values. I need something generic that can use long ints for keys and my own objects as values. I could roll my own by using a hash table with the hash table holding a list for each key. I would rather have library code that is robust and may be more efficient.

Comment: What would it mean to have multiple objects with the same unique identifier? What would you expect to get back when you ask for the key and there are multiple objects with that key?

Comment: Why don't you just use dictionary? here is the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: if you only need to populate it from existing data: ToLookup does this; no Add etc though

Comment: Joe, I would expect to get back a list. For instance, I have a list of retail stores and I want to be able to do the quickest search possible for all stores for a specific retail chain ID. Then I need to look for all employees for a given store ID in the employee data. I want to have things hashed to avoid writing code to loop through an entire list while comparing chain ID's or store ID's.

And I never used the word "Unique" in my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure! You could do this:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<long, List<MyType>>();
```

Adding a values would work like this:

```
dict[key] = new List<MyType>(valuesEnumerable);
```

Or if you want to add an object to an existent key:

```
dict[key].Add(value);
```

Comment: @Kritner Exactly. It's a list of values for each key.

Comment: ah, my mistake! :)

Comment: I wrapped this dictionary in a class of its own to let me simplify the Add(), Remove(), etc., process with custom functions.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `MultiValueDictionary` (NuGet: [Microsoft.Experimental.Collections](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Experimental.Collections)): https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2014/08/05/multidictionary-becomes-multivaluedictionary/

```
var multiValueDictionary = new MultiValueDictionary<string, int>();
multiValueDictionary.Add("key", 1);
multiValueDictionary.Add("key", 2);
//multiValueDictionary.Count == 1
//multiValueDictionary.Values contains elements [[1,2]]
```

Comment: Why not just `Dictionary<string, List<int>>`? (for example)

Comment: The downside of using a normal `Dictionary` @Camilo is that you need to, on every addition to a list, check whether you need to `new` the `List` up. The `MultiDictionary` abstracts that away so you don't need to think about it. _That being said, your idea will definitely work._

Comment: @mjwills I'd rather abstract that logic away in my own code that depend on the implementation of a library, but that's just me :)